# show local time in HTML from python

Tags: python, datetime

I am a very new programmer and I need help adjusting the following python code so that it will adjust the unix time pulled in from a database to the local browser time(date actually):

SCRIPT:

```
def format_utc(self, timestamp):
      return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

It currently only pulls the original unix time and converts it to UTC instead of local. Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: You need a database connection, an appropriate query and parsing the results. This is somewhat complex for a single question. I would recommend you to try each step and post questions if you encounter specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

`fromtimestamp()` returns *local* time (on the server). If it you see UTC time; it means that the server's timezone is set to UTC.

`format_utc()` name is misleading `fromtimestamp()` accepts "seconds since the epoch" number such as returned by `time.time()` function. It is the same number in all timezones e.g., the value won't change if you change your local timezone.

To display local time in the browser, put the timestamp into html as is and use javascript to convert the timestamp into client's local time.